# Read files in Phoenix in production mode

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, edeliver, distillery

I've Phoenix app (I created it with --api flag) that has some additional data required to process requests that I store in `priv/data/filters.csv`.

So it works fine in `dev` mode, I can read this file like: `File.stream!("priv/data/filters.csv")`, but once app is delivered using `mix edeliver update` this file is not accessible anymore.

I can see this folder in build directory, but after app is delivered there is no such folder `priv`. I'm not sure why it's not copied to deliver folder.

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need to copy these files after deliver process?
Where can I store my files that I have to use in prod mode?

Comment: What is the content of `rel/config.exs`?

Comment: Try `File.stream!(Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:my_app), "data/filters.csv"))`.

Comment: One quick way to test this is to open a remote_console to your production instance. You can then type `pwd` in iex to see where your relative path starts. Then try the call to `:code.priv_dir(:my_app)` and very the absolute path.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use `:code.priv_dir/1` to get the absolute path to the `priv` directory of your application at runtime. This will work with Erlang releases created by e.g. Distillery:

```
File.stream!(Path.join(:code.priv_dir(:my_app), "data/filters.csv"))
```

For me, after doing `MIX_ENV=prod mix release`, the file `priv/foo` is copied to `_build/prod/lib/my_app/priv/foo`.

Comment: God bless ya, it works! And now I know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and managed to resolve it using `Application.app_dir(my_app, "priv")`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your configuration in the `lib/YOUR_APP/endpoint.ex`. 
By default `Plug.Static` white lists the files that are served.
Try adding your files at the `only: ~w(...)` list.

Comment: Yes, but I didn't see usual static files either. It because I misunderstood file structure, and I had to for `priv` folder  in the `deilver_path/lib/app_version/` folder, not in the `deliver_path` itself.